# How to add my facebook app to my facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-group

I have Created a Facebook app which is used to publish content to facebook pages and Group. But recent Facebook API Changes not allowed to post on group without installing my app to that group

When Try to add by Group setting, My facebook app is not listed.

Can any one help me to how to add my facebook app to the list to add /install in the group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have submitted for the review to access group api, now its working fine